# Spring model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to set to different data,like

```
    SoyMapData dataFormsMenu=new SoyMapData(
            "class","menu horizontal",
            "caption","",
            "id","dfMenu",
            "innerContainer","div",
            "helper","span",
            "items",new SoyListData( 
            new SoyMapData ("caption", "Manage Dataforms",
                    "class", "",
                    "link", "#"),
                    new SoyMapData("caption", "viewForm",
                    "class", "",
                    "link", "#")
                    ));
      SoyMapData mainMenu = new SoyMapData(
                "class","menu horizontal dropdown",
                "caption","",
                "id","mainMenu",
                "container","div",
                "contClass","navigation main left",
                "items",captionData);
```

into model object of spring,

```
model.addattribute("",mainmenu);
model.addattribute("",dfmenu);
```

how to do this in spring.

Comment: create a bean for all simple objects; then connect them to get your complex object. For example, create a bean for each simple SoyMapData objects (one for "Manage Dataform, one for ""viewForm" ...), then use them to get dataFormsMenu bean object by setting property/via constructor

Comment: i want to set this in a method like  into model object of spring, in a single method,i want to set this in a method like  @RequestMapping("/forms/dataform.jsp")
 public void renderMethod3(Model model) {
  
  model.addAttribute("pageTitles", "This is a data form");
model.addAttribute("pageTitles", "This is a data form");
     
 } this model object will be used by resolver to render,i don't have any jsp,i am using tempaltes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) you are not talking about Spring, you are talking about Spring MVC, the MVC framework built upon the Spring framework. There's a difference.

b) you need to give the model attribute a name, e.g.

```
model.addattribute("main",mainmenu);
model.addattribute("df",dfmenu);
```

Then you can access the data from a JSP (or other view) using

`${main.id}` or `${main[id]}`,

depending on the inner workings of `SoyMapData`

Answer (score 0):

create a bean for all simple objects; then connect them to get your complex object. For example, create a bean for each simple SoyMapData objects (one for "Manage Dataform, one for ""viewForm" ...), then use them to get dataFormsMenu bean object by setting property/via constructor